# Custom URL button with Custom Setting field

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-button

We have the button (parameters in the screenshot):

[image]

Button or Link URL value is `{!URLFOR($Setup.TRHC__ConfigSettingsHierarchy__c.TRHC__InterviewFeedbackSiteURL__c)}TRHC__ShowJobInterviews?id={!TRHC__Job__c.Id}`.

The button's URL contains a domain from Custom Setting *TRHC__ConfigSettingsHierarchy__c.TRHC__InterviewFeedbackSiteURL__c*. Value of the Custom Setting is `https://truhealthcare-developer-edition.na80.force.com/`. The value is a URL to external *Salesforce Site*.

I expect when the button is clicked it will open the page like: `https://truhealthcare-developer-edition.na80.force.com/TRHC__ShowJobInterviews?id=a101P000004rzI4QAI`

But when I click the button on Lightning Experience it goes to URL `https://truhealthcare-developer-edition.na80.force.com`. And `/TRHC__ShowJobInterviews?id=a101P000004rzI4QAI` part is not there.

UPDATE 1:

When I change the Button URL to `{!$Setup.TRHC__ConfigSettingsHierarchy__c.TRHC__InterviewFeedbackSiteURL__c}TRHC__ShowJobInterviews?id={!TRHC__Job__c.Id}` it goes to `https://trhc-managed-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/one/https%3A%2F%2Ftruhealthcare-developer-edition.na80.force.com%2FTRHC__ShowJobInterviews?id=a101P000004rzI4` which is invalid URL.

UPDATE 2:

I changed the Button URL to `https://{!$Setup.TRHC__ConfigSettingsHierarchy__c.TRHC__InterviewFeedbackSiteURL__c}TRHC__ShowJobInterviews?id={!TRHC__Job__c.Id}` and modified the value of the custom setting to `truhealthcare-developer-edition.na80.force.com/`. When I click the button it shows a popup with the message `We'd like to open the Salesforce page null... in a new tab. Because of your browser settings, we need your permission first`. And if I click **OPEN** button on the popup it goes to `about:blank#blocked` URL.

How to make the Button URL work properly?

Comment: Don't know what else to say, then. I'm not sure you can do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to redirect to a URL, please try with a lightning component which can be then put inside a quick action. Take the custom setting and you can append the recordID in JS  in the component and make it redirect in the init of component.